# What is the view on climate by Mme de Staël that Vircondelet is referring to?

Tags: french-language, germaine-de-stael

In his biography *Albert Camus, fils d'Alger* ("Albert Camus, son of Algiers", Fayard 2010, Pluriel 2013) Alain Vircondelet describes the strong connection between Camus and Algeria, especially its capital Algiers.
One of the chapters describes a trip that Camus made (in 1937) to the French Prealps in [Haute-Savoie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haute-Savoie), where he did not feel at home at all.
Later on, he travels down to the South of France and Italy, where he feels much better, as can be seen from the entries in his notebooks (which have also been published: [*Carnets, tome I : Mai 1935 - février 1942*](http://www.gallimard.fr/Catalogue/GALLIMARD/Folio/Folio/Carnets2)). Vircondelet then adds:

> Véritable histoire des climats à la manière de Mme de Staël, écrite dans la joie et l'émotion.

English translation:

> A true/real history of climate in the style of Mme de Staël, written in state of joy and emotion.

What is Vircondelet referring to here? Did Germain de Staël ever formulate some sort of theory about a connection between climate and literature or does this refer to something that is implicitly present in her novels?

Comment: I am not sure what the difficulty is here. The quote says that the *style* of the piece resembles de Staël's style, not that the *subject* of the piece resembles de Staël's subject.

Comment: @GarethRees That may be an easy assumption to make, but is it actually correct?